# Using a component as a header title in React Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to put a component as my stack navigator header title. This is the code:

```
const Test = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Test1</Text>
      <Text>Test2</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const stackNav = createStackNavigator(
  {
    ProductionList: {
      screen: List,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: {
          title: <Test />
        }
      }
    },
    ProductionBoard: {
      screen: Board
    }
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: colors.dark
      },
      headerTintColor: "#fff",
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: "bold"
      }
    }
  }
);
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: renderHeader is not a function

This error is located at:
    in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
    in withOrientation (at StackView.js:58)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at Transitioner.js:146)
    in Transitioner (at StackView.js:22)
    in StackView (at createNavigator.js:96)
    in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:11)
    in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:393)
    in NavigationContainer (at SceneView.js:10)
    in SceneView (at createTabNavigator.js:10)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at ResourceSavingScene.js:14)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at ResourceSavingScene.js:10)
    in ResourceSavingScene (at createBottomTabNavigator.js:83)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at createBottomTabNavigator.js:74)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at createBottomTabNavigator.js:73)
    in TabNavigationView (at createTabNavigator.js:91)
    in NavigationView (at createNavigator.js:96)
    in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:393)
    in NavigationContainer (at SceneView.js:10)
    in SceneView (at SwitchView.js:12)
    in SwitchView (at createNavigator.js:96)
    in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:393)
    in NavigationContainer (at App.js:56)
    in RCTSafeAreaView (at SafeAreaView.ios.js:34)
    in SafeAreaView (at AppContainer.js:30)
    in AppContainer (at App.js:55)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:33)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:32)
```

Any ideas on how to solve that?

Comment: Are you sure the code you shared is the source of the error? Not seeing them in the error stack.

Comment: The error happens inside React Navigator (RN). All the call stack are internal functions from RN....

Comment: and I see this is the only place where the function is used https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/46ffb106278425631c26049fa50b185e90789c9c/Libraries/Lists/ListView/ListView.js

Comment: The starting point: [react-navigation header title](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html)

Answer (score 3):

You should use `headerTitle` instead of `header: { title`.

```
navigationOptions: {
  headerTitle: // your custom component here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Theres been some changes to the navigation options in `react-navigation`, version 2 now takes different arguments.

This:

```
navigationOptions: {
        header: {
          title: <Test />
        }
      }
```

Can now be done like this

```
navigationOptions: {
      header: <Test />
    }
```

or

```
navigationOptions: {
          headerTitle: <Test />
        }
```

Comment: I'm aware of it, but using this way the header does not shows up on screen, getting an empty header title...

Comment: are you using v1 or v2 of `react-navigation`?

Comment: I'm using the latest version (2.0.4)

Comment: sorry, i updated the answer, `headerTitle` is what you use now. Also the latest version is (2.12.0) if you want to update your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use custom header do this, with react-navigation you have some limitations.

```
    static navigationOptions = {
          header : null
      };


    <View style={styles.header}>
             <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.backButton}
                  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
                    <Image
                      source= 
                      {require("../../../../public/Assets/images/ArrowBack.png")}
                     />
           </TouchableOpacity>
           <Text style={styles.backTitle}>Title</Text>
        </View>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    header: {
        flexDirection: "row",
        backgroundColor: "#F5F5F5",
        paddingTop : Platform.OS == 'ios' ? 20 : 0,
    }

 backTitle: {
    fontFamily: Fonts.GothamMedium,
    fontSize: 20,
    marginLeft : 10,
    marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 24 : 16,
    marginBottom: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 20 : 19,
    color: "#414042",
  },
});
```